# Linkedin Group API call get profile URL of the commented member

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using Linkedin REST API with PHP.

I am trying to get posts of a particular discussion group.

The API call is

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/2417328/posts:(creation-timestamp,summary,title,type,comments,id,creator:(picture-url,last-name,headline,id,first-name,site-standard-profile-request))?count=100&start=0&modified-since=1312441200000

I would like to fetch the profile URL of the members who commented on each post also. Is it possible to do this with the above mentioned call?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible - in the API call, specify the comment creator fields you would like to return from the list of available [Profile Fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields). To return the comment creator's profile URL, replace the `comments` [Group Field](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-fields) with `comments:(creator:(site-standard-profile-request))`. You can specify other profile fields in there as needed.